# javafx scrollbar

Tags: scrollbar, javafx

I'm very new to javafx. I am trying to add a horizontal scroll bar to my stage. I've got a very wide picture and I'd like to show only part of it and allow the user to scroll it. How is it done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to bind `value` of scrollbar to translateX (or Y) of image. And of course set min and max of scrollbar to 0, image.width (.height)

Answer (score 1):

```
Image roses = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("roses.jpg"));
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
sp.setContent(new ImageView(roses)); //result 1

sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);// add for result 2
sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
```

Result:

[image]

Result with setHbarPolicy and setVbarPolicy:

[image]

greetings Kaito

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ScrollPane and inside that ScrollPane put your picture.

In the Scenebuilder:

AnchorPane
-->ScrollPane
 --> AnchorPane (with Big Picture)